# SCPI LAN Measurement

Tags: lan, oscilloscope

I am trying to com with a scope over LAN that supports SCPI. Link is established I can ;

*RST
*CLS

but I can't do ;

:MEASure:SOURce CH1

it returns zero. To be more clear ;

```
a = SCPI(host, timeout=0.5)
a.ask('SYST:ERR?');
a.write('*RST'); a.write('*CLS');
a.ask(":MEASure:SOURce CH1");
```

returns ;

```
>> SYST:ERR? 
<<  
>> SYST:ERR? 
<<  
>> :MEASure:SOURce CH1 
<<  
>> SYST:ERR? 
<<
```

doing *IDN? retuns successfully.

What might be going on ? It's a OWON XDS device.

Comment: Do you have the programming manual for it?

Comment: I think most scope are just ":MEASure SOURce 1" and not a "CH1".  Ie, Keysight/Aligent scopes are like this.  Also, after the ":MEASure", you can do a ":MEASure?" should show an update.  Some commands don't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check the device you're communicating with. What terminating characters does it require?

Does Measure command require question mark to indicate a request?

It appears that *RST and *CLS are not working. The response is an error.